# TCP retransmission for the same packet but with the different TCP payload

Tags: linux-kernel, drivers, tcp

I'm developing an Ethernet driver in Linux platform. I found that when a TCP retransmission occurred, the TCP payloads of multiple retransmission packets referring to the same sequence number packets were different. I can't understand why it would happen. In my driver, I just allocated a normal network device without any specific flags. By the way, the TCP checksum field was also wrong in these retransmission packets, however, the checksum in all the other types of TCP packets was right, such as SYNC, ACK, and DUP ACK.

I captured the packets by wireshark, and it means the packets I captured were not handled by my driver, just from the TCP stack in Linux kernel. But when I tested with other Ethernet devices and drivers, this problem didn't happen. So my questions were like the following.

1. Is there any possible for TCP stack to retransmit the same packets without same payload?
2. Which kinds of parameters in Linux kernel would cause these problem?
3. How can my driver cause this problem?

Comment: You just say they were "different" but don't really explain what you were looking at when you found them to be different. In what way are they different?

Comment: I'm guessing http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/196341/problem-for-tcp-retransmission is also yours, it appears you have two users. So you may not have seen the suggestion on the other one that you're probably better off asking on [so] and including code if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

Thx for all your reply.

I found the reason for this problem. It's a very very fool fault.

Due to making all the DMA buffers (in my driver it's skb->data)address aligned to 4bytes, I called a memmove function to do that. Actually, the data referred by the skb->data is shared by all the TCP/IP stack in the Kernel. So after this wrong operation, when the TCP retranmission occurs, the address referred by skb->data in TCP stack still maintains the original one. That's why the checksum based on original data seems wrong in wireshark. The codes in my driver is like the following.

```
u32 skb_len = skb->len;
u32 align = check_aligned(skb);
if !align
    return skb;

skb_push(skb,align);
memmove(skb->data, skb->data+align, skb_len);
skb_trim(skb, skb_len);
return skb;
```

I hope my experience can help others to avoid this fool fault.